# Class is covered but showing coverage 0%

Tags: unit-test

My class is getting covered but shows 0% coverage. Not able to find out which lines are covered.

Comment: How do you know your class is covered? Where are you seeing 0% code coverage?

Comment: In developer console its showing in Class COde Coverage section its showing coverage of 67%, but on class its showing 0%.

Comment: This is likely an issue with cached coverage data about the class which you're testing which has been stored. If you wait a few minutes, you will probably see more accurate per-line coverage information. If you run your test(s) via Eclipse you will be able to get immediate results of test information including lines covered.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since our sandbox is on winter14. I run a test in Eclipse and get x% coverage returned in the result. If I then go to the class in the browser it shows 0% coverage. If I run the test from the browser it passes but still shows 0% coverage. I suspect it is a bug although I cannot find any reference on salesforce. There is one issue :https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0kUAAS that might be your problem. It is not the problem I'm getting though.

Comment: hi guys, I am having the same problem. If I chose All Test, code coverage is showing 0%. I can't see which lines are covered or not. Even I choose each method (let's say 50%) , I still can't see lines and color coverage. It is so difficult to trace. Anyone has hint or walkaround ?

Comment: I want to say that I have had this issue in the past. I believe clearing out my test history solved this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run your unit test in an org with no data

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: When you are running unit tests it should create its own data to be used, if you leave data around when running the test it will get upset. 
Also the unit test will just pass regardless of a failing test or not. You can write your unit test to be able to run in an org with data but it is a bad idea.

Comment: Unit tests do not get upset. Unit test code should create data to be used during the test, this is correct. Unit test code _will_ pass unless assertions in the test code verifying proper behavior cause it to fail. After a unit test runs, the data from the test is discarded. Unit tests must be able to run in an org which has existing data. Unit test code should not anticipate any data being available in the org in which the test is being executed.